# using LDAP for Apache Drill

Tags: active-directory, ldap, apache-drill

I want the Apache Drill WebUI to be secured by LDAP authentication, any ideas on how to get this to work?

I was able to setup Azkaban using LDAP as follows:

```
user.manager.ldap.host=ldap.example.com
user.manager.ldap.port=636
user.manager.ldap.useSsl=true
user.manager.ldap.userBase=dc=example,dc=com
user.manager.ldap.userIdProperty=uid
user.manager.ldap.emailProperty=mail
user.manager.ldap.bindAccount=cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com
user.manager.ldap.bindPassword=password
user.manager.ldap.allowedGroups=azkaban-ldap-group
user.manager.ldap.groupSearchBase=ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
user.manager.ldap.embeddedGroups=false
```

something similar would amazing.

Comment: were you able to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Drill's WebServer uses PAM modules to do authentication based on username and password. If you have LDAP setup in your environment (am not expert on how to do one and it is nothing specific to Drill. For ref: please look [1](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/LDAP-Implementation-HOWTO/pamnss.html)) then the pam modules should be able to use that infrastructure. All you need is to create a pam profile under (/etc/pam.d/) which meets your security requirement and configure that pam profile to be used by Drill. Example configuration is shared at [2](https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-plain-authentication/).